# Density of Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

> Is the Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R}^3)$ dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for $s>0$ ?

Answer (score 2):

We denote by $\mathcal D(\Bbb R^d)$ the set of smooth functions with compact support.

- As the Fourier transform of a function in $\mathcal D(\Bbb R^d)$ has an arbitrary decay, we have the inclusion $\mathcal D(\Bbb R^d)\subset H^s(\Bbb R^d)$ for any $s>0$.
- By Plancherel's formula, we have $H^s(\Bbb R^d)\subset L^2(\Bbb R^d)$.
- By a truncation and regularization argument, it can be shown that $\mathcal D(\Bbb R^d)$ in dense in $L^2(\Bbb R^d)$ with its natural norm.

Comment: Your last Point mean that the closure of $\mathcal{D}(R^d)$ equals $L^2(R^d)$, i.e. $\text{cl}\mathcal{D}(R^d)=L^2(R^d)$, right? But why do $\mathcal{D}(R^d)\subset H^s(R^d)\subset L^2(R^d)$ and $\text{cl}\mathcal{D}(R^d)=L^2(R^d)$ imply that $\text{cl}H^s(R^d)=L^2(R^d)$? Is this because in General, if $A\subset B\subset C=cl(A) $ we have $cl(A)\subset cl(B)\subset cl(C)=cl(A)$ and hence all the "$\subset$" are in fact "="?